# error configurando eslint

Tags: javascript, vue.js

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

el error me sale en este linea 
webpack
var path = require('path')
y en .eslintrc tengo

### "parser":"babel-eslint"

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

asi estoy configurando babel-eslint ... Pero en el Package.json no me sale el modulo

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Que fue lo que cambiaste en eslint?

Comment: ¿Cómo instalaste ese módulo?

Comment: Sebastian podrías mostrarme tu package.json completo?

Comment: @fredyfx Mira en la parte de abajo , así lo estoy instalando

Comment: @FrancoGallo en mi package.json , no esta el modulo, es por eso el error y no se como instalarlo

Comment: Por favor, no uses imágenes salvo que sea absolutamente necesario. Mira por favor [aca](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3976/324). Los errores y tu codigo deben ir como texto, siempre.